# Why does perl have floating point errors here?

Tags: perl, floating-point

I have this code:

```
sub range {
        my ($start, $end, $step) = @_;

        if($step == 0) {
                die("Step size cannot be 0!")
        }
        if($start > $end) {
                ($start, $end) = ($end, $start);
        }
        my @range = ();
        for (my $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += $step) {
                push @range, $i;
        }

        return @range;
}
```

When running

```
my @range = range(-3, -2.7, 0.01);
```

I get this list:

```
...
$VAR23 = '-2.78';
$VAR24 = '-2.77';
$VAR25 = '-2.76000000000001';
$VAR26 = '-2.75000000000001';
$VAR27 = '-2.74000000000001';
$VAR28 = '-2.73000000000001';
$VAR29 = '-2.72000000000001';
$VAR30 = '-2.71000000000001';
$VAR31 = '-2.70000000000001';
```

Why does this happen?

I have perl v5.24.1 on a 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.107-1 machine. Adding the bignum module does not change the fact that the variables calculated are wrong.

Also, this does not happen when doing sometheng like "-2.7 - 0.01".

Comment: please could you show us an example of your call to range. e.g., range(1,10,1);

Comment: I think this is a display issue with floats. try running it with  
printf("%.2f\n" , $_) for @range; instead of Data::Dumper

Comment: Interestingly `my @range = map { -3 + $_/100 } 0..30` does not give me round-off errors

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, Sure it does. It's impossible to store a number that's periodic in binary into a floating point number. You can see the error with `printf("%.20g", $_);`. It does have the benefit of avoiding error *accumulation*.

Comment: @JonathanGreszwinsky The problem is that 1/10 is periodic in binary (just like 1/3 is in decimal), so it can't be stored accurately in a floating point number. On top of that, you make the problem worse by repeatedly adding inaccurate numbers.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this happen?

See **[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/)**.

> Adding the bignum module does not change the fact that the variables calculated are wrong.

I'm guessing that you added the `use bignum;` inside of `sub range`, but because [`bignum`](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html) is scoped, this won't automatically affect the variables passed into that `sub`. So either `bignum` needs to be in effect wherever the literals that you pass into `range` are defined and it'll work, or, you could just upgrade the variables in the `sub` itself, as in:

```
use Math::BigRat;
sub range {
    my $start = Math::BigRat->new(shift);
    my $end   = Math::BigRat->new(shift);
    my $step  = Math::BigRat->new(shift);
    ...
    return map {$_->numify} @range;
}
```

**However**, using the [`Math::BigRat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigRat.html), `Math::BigFloat`, etc. (including via the `bignum` and related pragmas) objects everywhere will slow down the code, so this may be overkill. So that the objects are used only within the `sub` above, I'm downgrading the objects back into regular scalars with `numify`, but that's optional depending on your performance requirements.

Depending on what precision you actually need, you could also round your numbers off via e.g. `sprintf("%.2f",$i)` (just as an example: `for (my $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i = 0+sprintf("%.2f",$i+$step) )`).
Another possibility, as pointed out by @ikegami in the comment, would be to work with integers and do the division last, as in e.g. `map { $_/100 } -300 .. -270`.

Comment: BigFloat would still suffer form the same problem. No matter how big you make the float, you can't store a number that's periodic in binary into a float. BigRat could work, but that's surely overkill. `map { $_ / 0.01 } -300 .. -270` would avoid error accumulation, and rounding or tolerances can handle the rest.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, edited. The extra `use bignum;` was a vestige from my test code that I forgot to remove, and I switched my example code over to `Math::BigRat` because my point was to show how to do it with as much accuracy as possible, but I highlighted that it may be overkill.